# Is the triple quotation mark legitimate (for translated foreign language quote)?

Tags: punctuation

I was watching *Last Week Tonight* with John Oliver, and I noticed that it seemed that when he was quoting a foreign speaker, but in English, the written quote on the screen used a triple quotation mark:

[image: triple quotation mark last week tonight]

I haven't seen this before, nor can I find it in the Unicode character chart or as a ligature. Is this something new, or am I misinterpreting what it means? Or maybe it was just a typo?

EDIT: I don't believe this is a duplicate question, as it seems to be simply a triple-quote mark, and not more than one speaker, or a quote-of-a-quote. That said, I did find another clip from the same show that does have the double-then-single quote, used in the traditional way:

[image]

The triple quote at the beginning does look identical, so my assumption is that the first picture above is just a typo. I do find it interesting that it almost looks like a ligature.

Comment: It’s not three sets of quotation marks. It’s one double quotation mark (“) and one single quotation mark (‘) right after each other, so you get “‘ and it’s counterpart. See the question which this one is probably a duplicate of.

Comment: @user1284969632635 Oh -- is it a quote from a magazine, that is quoting the speaker?

Comment: @Chris It is quoting *something* (whether a magazine or another speaker) that is quoting Berlusconi. The latter’s words are set off by single quotes, and the whole sentence is within double quotes.

Comment: @user1284969632635 Got it -- that was the part I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems merely a typesetting peculiarity.